# I need to send a Expo Notification once a day, but it is sending many push to same user

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using Expo to send a daily notification at 4:30 pm, without access back end (just local).

It is working well, but not right, once it is sending many pushs to the same user.

I don't know if there is something about useEffect params, but if I do not consider anything inside of [ ], notification is not sent.

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications'

import api from '../api'
import { userStatusStorage } from '../../utils/defaultValues'
import { useAuth } from './auth'

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
   handleNotification: async () => ({
      shouldShowAlert: true,
      shouldPlaySound: false,
      shouldSetBadge: false,
   }),
});

export const NotificationContext = createContext({});

export function NotificationProvider({ children }) {
   const [idUser, setIdUser] = useState()

   const [userObj, setUserObj] = useState({})

   const [status, setStatus] = useState('')
   const [notificationStatusPermission, setNotificationStatusPermission] = useState(true)

   const [token, setToken] = useState('')
   const [expoPushTokenDevice, setExpoPushTokenDevice] = useState('')
   const [notificationSent, setNotificationSent] = useState({})

   const { userId, idStorage, user, userStorage, statusStorage, userStatus } = useAuth()

   const notificationListener = useRef();
   const responseListener = useRef();

 
   useEffect(() => {
      if (userId) {
         setIdUser(userId)

      } else {
         setIdUser(idStorage)
      }

   }, [userId, idStorage])

   useEffect(() => {
      if (Object.keys(userStorage).length !== 0) {
         setUserObj(JSON.parse(userStorage))

      } else {
         setUserObj(user)
      }

   }, [userStorage])

   useEffect(() => {
      if (status !== '') {
         return

      } else if (userStatus) {
         setStatus(userStatus)

      } else {
         setStatus(statusStorage)
      }

   }, [statusStorage, userStatus])


   useEffect(() => {
      try {
         Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync().then(token => setExpoPushTokenDevice(token));
      } catch (e) {
         setExpoPushTokenDevice('token');
      }

      registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setToken(token));

      notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
         setNotificationSent(notification);
      });

      responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
         // called at the moment that user tap on notification bar
         const url = response.notification.request.content.data.url;
         Linking.openURL(url);
      });

      return () => {
         Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener);
         Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener);
      };
   }, []);

    
   useEffect(() => {
      sendNotification()

   }, [idUser])

   async function sendNotification() {
      if (notificationStatusPermission) {
         await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            content: {
               title: `Olá ${userObj.name.split(' ')[0]}`,
               body: `Seu status atual é ${status}!`,
               data: {
                  data: idUser,
                  url: 'gogogo://'
               },
            },
            trigger: { hour: 16, minute: 30, repeats: true },
         });
      }
   }

   async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
      let token;
      const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
         const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
         finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
         alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
         return;
      }
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;

      setToken(token)

      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
         Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
         });
      }

      return token;
   }


   async function loadStatus() {
      const res = await api.get('myStatusDaily')

      await AsyncStorage.setItem(userStatusStorage, res.data[0].name)
      setStatus(res.data[0].name)
      setNotificationStatusPermission(res.data[0].notificationPermission)
   }

   return (
      <NotificationContext.Provider
         value={{
            status,
            notificationStatusPermission,
            loadStatus,
         }}
      >
         {children}

      </NotificationContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

How can I garantee that will be sent just one notification per day?